# How can I monitor BFD flaps?

Tags: cisco, snmp

We need to monitor BFD flaps on our Cisco Nexus devices but the problem is that Zabbix do SNMP polling every 1 minute, and we can't detect, for example, 5 sec BFD flaps. We detect only if BFD down for a minute.
Maybe BFD have some up/down counter or other mechanism which help us to monitor flaps? Have you some other ideas to sovle this issue maybe?

Comment: Have you tried SNMP *traps*?

Comment: You should have a logging server and set up your devices to use it.

Comment: @Zac67, no, we don't. This is the key for us?

Comment: @RonMaupin, do you mean syslog server?  Yes, we have it, but it's not enough. A message will appear on the syslog, but we want the zabbix to react to it and alert. It is difficult to make the connection between zabbix and syslog in this case, as the logic of the BFD falls is not simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trap should be the right approach to 'instantly' notify Zabbix of the problem. Polling is fine for statistics and overall monitoring but problems should be 'trapped'.

You'll need to set up Zabbix's trap receiver and something along `snmp-server enable traps bfd session-up/down` on the Nexus.

https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_bfd/configuration/15-1sg/irb-bfd-mib.html